# Scala: Calculate Sum

Tags: scala

Assume following simple code in Scala that calculates the sum

```
var sum = 0
for (xs <- xss; x <- xs) sum +=x
```

Calculating the sum this way has side affects. How should I do this without side affects?

Answer (score 1):

assuming your `xss` is `List of List`,

```
scala> val collection = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8))
collection: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8))

scala> var sum = 0
sum: Int = 0

scala> for (xs <- collection; x <- xs) sum +=x

scala> sum
res4: Int = 36
```

shorter way would be to flatten your collection and sum the elements

```
scala> collection.flatten.sum
res7: Int = 36
```

also, you could have folded the collection the way you want.

```
scala> collection.flatten.foldLeft(0)((a, b) => a + b)
res9: Int = 36

// or without flattening
scala> collection.foldLeft(0)((a, b) => a + b.sum)
res14: Int = 36
```

or could have `reducedLeft`,

```
scala> collection.flatten.reduceLeft((a, b) => a + b)
res10: Int = 36
```

but since theres `.sum` on collection you should go with `.sum`.

Comment: `flatten` is not needed while folding: `xss.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.sum)`

Comment: @jwvh true, can do that way too. `collection.foldLeft(0)((a, b) => a + b.sum)` Thx